# How to add new constructor that will not break OOP principle?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a wrapper class to work with `IAsyncCursor` that returns `IEnumerable<TResult>`

My program can take items from two places:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> GetItems()
{
    List<TResult> fromA = fromA();
    IEnumerable<TResult> fromB = fromB();

    var result = fromA.Concat(fromB).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

But I don't want to store the `result` in memory because its too expensive.

I would like to change my return result of `GetItems()` to returns `ResultCollection` and have the ability to call `Dispose()`

So, I need to change the result from `fromA()` and `fromB()` methods to returns `ResultCollection`, like the following

```
ResultCollection<TResult> GetItems()
{
    ResultCollection<TResult> fromA = fromA(); // wrap List<TResult> to ResultCollection
    ResultCollection<TResult> fromB = fromB(); // return collection that I can dispose when I need

    return new ResultCollection<TResult>(fromA.Concat(fromB).ToList());
}
```

How do I need to change my `ResultCollection` to store `List` constructor? I need that this new class correspond all `OOP` and `SOLID` principle.

I don't need to have just another constructor inside `ResultCollection` like this

```
public ResultCollection(IList<TResult> list)
{
    _list = list;
}
```

Comment: Couldn’t you change your collection to just take multiple cursors, which would then be chained internally? So you could just do `return new DeferredResultCollection<TResult>(fromA(), fromB())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new interface called `IDisposableEnumerable` that have the following definition:

```
public interface IDisposableEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IDisposable
{

}
```

And then make your `DeferredResultCollection` class implement such interface.

Then you should create another implementation of such interface that wraps any `IEnumerable<T>`. Such class can be called `EnumerableWrapper` and it does nothing inside its `Dispose` method.

You would also need to create another implementation that can concatinate two (or more) `IDisposableEnumerable` objects together using the [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), such class can be called `CompositeDisposableEnumerable`.

Please note that your `DeferredResultCollection` class blocks when invoking asynchronous methods which is not optimal.

You might also want to consider using [Reactive Extensions for .NET](https://rx.codeplex.com/), but that is whole different thing that will probably cause design changes.

**UPDATE:**

Here is how `EnumerableWrapper` and `CompositeDisposableEnumerable` would look like:

```
public class EnumerableWrapper<T> : IDisposableEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> m_Enumerable;

    public EnumerableWrapper(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        m_Enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_Enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable) m_Enumerable).GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class CompositeDisposableEnumerable<T> : IDisposableEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IDisposableEnumerable<T>[] m_DisposableEnumerables;

    public CompositeDisposableEnumerable(params IDisposableEnumerable<T>[] disposable_enumerables)
    {
        m_DisposableEnumerables = disposable_enumerables;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var disposable_enumerable in m_DisposableEnumerables)
        {
            foreach (var item in disposable_enumerable)
                yield return item;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var disposable_enumerable in m_DisposableEnumerables)
            disposable_enumerable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a sample usage:

```
public IDisposableEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>()
{
    List<T> collection1 = ....;

    DeferredResultCollection<T> collection2 = new DeferredResultCollection<T> (async_cursor);

    return new CompositeDisposableEnumerable<T>(new EnumerableWrapper<T>(collection1), collection2);

}
```

And from the consumer side:

```
using(var items = GetItems<string>())
{
    //do something with items
} //This will invoke `Dispose` which will be propagated finally to DeferredResultCollection.Dispose and thus to IAsyncCursor.Dispose
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code that implement Composite Pattern, because I have problem with them. Thank you very much.

Comment: You think that I need to use `usr` idea?

Comment: @Anatoly, I would say that my approach is safer. I am putting the responsibility of disposing the resource on the final consumer. @usr approach has some advantages. It does not require a lot of code, and you can normally use LINQ methods to compose your sequences. And the most important advantage of his approach is that the consumer does not have to explicitly to call `Dispose`.

Comment: @Anatoly, Please read the comments on @usr answer, I think that it has some limitations, but these might not apply to you. Also you might want to consider to use a `Lazy` parameter with @usr approach. I proposed such proposal in one of my comments on his answer.

Comment: Where in your answer I can use `Lazy` parameter ?

Comment: @Anatoly, I was proposing to use `Lazy` with @usr approach, not mine.

Comment: Can you explaine please, why do I need to have `CompositeDisposableEnumerable` ?

Comment: @Anatoly, you need it to be able to concatenate two disposable-enumerables. You cannot use the `Concat` LINQ method because it does not return a disposable-enumerable. See my update for a sample usage.

Comment: You are genius. Thank you very much!

Comment: In your example  `return new CompositeDisposableEnumerable<T>(new EnumerableWrapper<T>(collection1), collection2);`  constructor has 1 parameter but is invoked with 2 arguments

Comment: @Anatoly, are you defining the `CompositeDisposableEnumerable` as in my code? Notice that it accepts an array. Also notice that this array has the [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`GetItems` should not return a `DeferredResultCollection`. It should return `IEnumerable<...>`. And then you can just do

```
return fromA.Concat(fromB);
```

Which will be completely lazy.

The whole class `DeferredResultCollection` should never be exposed to consumers of this API because it has no useful public members. `IEnumerable<...>` is totally enough.

In fact, the class `DeferredResultCollection` is not needed at all. You could replace it with an iterator.

---

Here's a fleshed out version:

1. Delete DeferredResultCollection
2. Use this:

.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> CreateDeferredIEnumerable(IAsyncCursor<TResult> _asyncCursor)
{
    if (_asyncCursor != null)
    {
        using (_asyncCursor) { //This is key
         for (; _asyncCursor.MoveNextAsync().Result;)
         {
             foreach (var result in _asyncCursor.Current)
             {
                 yield return result;
             }
         }
        } //The Dispose is always triggered!
    }
}
```

This always disposes resources, even in these sample cases:

```
1. ((IDisposable)CreateDeferredIEnumerable(...)).Dispose();
1. ((IDisposable)CreateDeferredIEnumerable(...).GetEnumerator()).Dispose();
2. CreateDeferredIEnumerable(...).ToList();
3. CreateDeferredIEnumerable(...).Take(1).ToList();
4. foreach (var x in CreateDeferredIEnumerable(...)) break;
```

---

In order to support concat we need to ensure disposal:

```
tatic IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
    using (first as IDisposable) {
    using (secondas IDisposable) {
    foreach (TSource iteratorVariable0 in first)
    {
        yield return iteratorVariable0;
    }
    foreach (TSource iteratorVariable1 in second)
    {
        yield return iteratorVariable1;
    }
    }
    }
}
```

I hope this works, it's quickly hacked together. It can be made to work for sure, though.

Comment: How would OP dispose of the `IAsyncCursor` in this case?

Comment: He needs to modify GetEnumerator to dispose the cursor when it's done.

Comment: But what if the consumer of the enumerable decided to take only some of the items?

Comment: Then, the iterator will be disposed early which triggers any using and finally blocks. This causes disposal. This really is no special case. Methods like File.EnumerateAllLines do it exactly like that.

Comment: Can you please explain how that can be done? How would the enumerator know that the consumer wishes to dispose? As far as the enumerator is concerned, the consumer called `MoveNext` a few times and that's it.

Comment: Where can I find the `File.EnumerateAllLines` method?

Comment: The consumer also calls Dispose when he wants to stop enumerating. foreach does that, it's the convention. Dispose then cleans up everything. Apparently, it's called File.ReadLines.

Comment: Let's say the someone invoked `fromA.Concat(fromB).Take(5).ToList();`, how would that force `IAsyncCursor` to get disposed? I still fail to see how this can be done. Where in the code should we call `_asyncCursor.Dispose();`?

Comment: Just wrap GetEnumerator in `using(_asyncCursor)`. Why wouldn't this work? It's just as if you called File.ReadLines(...).ToList();

Comment: I have seen your answer. You are relying on the same thing. You are relying on clients calling your Dispose method.

Comment: If you wrap `GetEnumerator` with `using(_asyncCursor)` and `GetEnumerator` uses the `yield` keyword, the the `_asyncCursor` will only be disposed of if the consumer of the enumerable enumerates all the items in the enumerable. If on the other hand, you don't use the `yield` keyword, then the `_asyncCursor` will be disposed of immediately before returning any items to the consumer.

Comment: Regarding my answer, I am giving the consumer of the high level enumerable (or disposable-enumerable) the ability to dispose of the resources by providing an interface that implements `IDisposable`. So the consumer can call dispose after he is done. If you compose multiple sequences together, the consumer can still dispose of the resources.

Comment: Please note that OP is returning such disposable-enumerable to the caller. The caller in this case does not know about `IAsyncCursor`. So what I am doing is giving the caller a way to dispose of the resources without knowing the details of what needs to be disposed of.

Comment: `will only be disposed of if the consumer of the enumerable enumerates all the items in the enumerable` no, as I said Dipose triggers all usings and finallys. This is a rule of the C# language. Just try it. `Regarding my answer, I am giving the consumer ` I do that as well, just more succinctly. Your answer works, of course.

Comment: Did you mean to return `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerator`?

Comment: When you foreach over it you first acquire an IEnumerator which is then disposed later. None of this is unique to this answer or controversial. Really, just try it, decompile it or just look it up in some tutorial.

Comment: I think that you have a point. I have done some tests and it works for most of the cases, I am still trying to figure out why it works. However, I still think you can still have a leak. Consider the case that the consumer obtained the enumerable but for some reasons, he decided not to enumerate it based on some condition.

Comment: Another example, if you concat two enumerables where the first one is a normal list and the second one the the enumrable that is wrapping the `_asyncCursor`. If the consumer decided to for example do `Take(5).ToList()` on the result and the list has 5 or more items, then the `_asyncCursor` will not be disposed of.

Comment: Anyway, thanks to you, I have learned something new today. I still need to investigate why it works.

Comment: He either needs to dispose or deplete the sequence. This is true regardless of what IEnumerable implementation is in use (e.g. in his DeferredResultCollection). With Concat you're right, the 2nd argument would not be touched by the BCL version. So we need a special Concat (see answer). Good point.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` does not have `Dispose()`, but you calling it `1. CreateDeferredIEnumerable(...).Dispose();`.

Comment: @PetSerAl correct, fixed. With an additional sample case.

Comment: That `((IDisposable)CreateDeferredIEnumerable(...).GetEnumerator()).Dispose()` will not dispose `_asyncCursor`. You need to call `MoveNext()` at least once to actually enter `using` block, without that `Dispose()` will do nothing.

Comment: If the `CreateDeferredIEnumerable` method has a `Lazy<IAsyncCursor<TResult>>` parameter instead of `IAsyncCursor<TResult>`, then the problem would be solved. If the enumerable is not used, then we wouldn't have to dispose of anything in the first place. This would however require the consumer to supply a lazy version that would open the resource (e.g. database) lazily.

Comment: @PetSerAl ah that's right. Not sure if this is acceptable to the OP. Would need to know the usage patterns. But this is hard to fix even with a custom class because you would need to caller to reliably call Dispose which is an uncommon thing to do on an IEnumerable. Maybe there is some value to having a custom class. (In other words: Maybe this answer does not work for him). I like Yacoubs idea of making CreateDeferredIEnumerable open the resource in the first place.